# declaration is incompatible with "std::vector<Comparable,

Tags: c++

I am getting an error with my `heapSort()`:

> declaration is incompatible with "std::vector<Comparable, std::allocator<Comparable>> BinaryHeap<Comparable>::heapsort()" (declared at line 46 of

I have a class `BinaryHeap` in a header file with all my function declarations. Heap sort is in there like this:

```
template <typename Comparable>
class BinaryHeap
{
public:
  ...
  vector<Comparable> heapsort();
  ...
private:
  ...
  void heapify(...);
}
```

My `heapsort()` function definition:

```
template <typename Comparable>
void BinaryHeap<Comparable>::heapsort() 
{
    
    // Build heap (rearrange array)
    for (int i = currentSize / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(array, currentSize, i);
 
    // One by one extract an element from heap
    for (int i = currentSize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        // Move current root to end
        swap(array[0], array[i]);
 
        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        heapify(array, i, 0);
    }    
}
```

Any recommendations on what I can do to fix this? All my other methods are working perfectly, and my `heapsort()` is clearly in the class `BinaryHeap`.

Comment: `heapsort` is not the same as `heapSort`. Capitalization matters.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]. We should be able to compile the example and get the same problem as you have.

Comment: @NathanPierson thanks i didnt even catch that. I changed it but now i am getting the error saying "declaration is incompatible with "std::vector<Comparable,"

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and the relevant code, like the definition of `heapSort`.

Comment: Hey @NathanPierson I just did that. My declaration is in the header file as "vector<Comparable> heapsort();" and the definiton is a type void. I think that might be the problem but i am not sure what type is right. I know that the template must be included.

Comment: So is the return type `vector<Comparable>` or `void`? Looks like that's the error's complaint too.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is incompatible with declaration.

Declaration:

```
vector<Comparable> heapsort();
```

Definition:

```
void BinaryHeap<Comparable>::heapsort()
```

You should decide which type your method should return, and use that same type in your declaration and definition.

For example, I think `void` makes sense as a return type (that is, the method should return nothing). If you agree, fix your declaration:

```
void heapsort();
```

However, maybe `vector<Comparable>` is actually the correct return type? If so, fix your definition:

```
template <typename Comparable>
vector<Comparable> BinaryHeap<Comparable>::heapsort() 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks this fixed the problem. I was just not sure how to start the function definition.